# Data Guard Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g

I want to do the disaster recovery in oracle 11g using data guard. But I don't the procedure or the way how to do it. I want all of someone that show me the document or the way to do it.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Thanks, Ung Sopolin

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[DataGuard starting with Rman](http://www.uaex.edu/srea/RMAN_Backups_and_Cloning.htm#Creating_a_Data_Guard_Standby_Database_Using_RMAN)

Comment: I think your reference note is very difficult to understand

Comment: I think your reference note is very difficult to understand. Could you find any example to me?

Comment: Sopolin, you need to deeply understand RMAN before you move to the next level of data assurance.

Comment: It looks like my link is dead.  Ill have to find another source.  kmarsh is correct.  You need to understand how RMAN works first before you can take full advantage of Dataguard.  Dataguard is rather complex and you may wish get a book.  It is larger than I can put into an answer here.